# How to create a chessboard with a nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Ok, so I have to make something that looks like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 1 0 0 0 

0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this, but I can't seem to find anything that works. Here is my code:

```
rows=int(input('Enter number of rows: '))

columns=int(input('Enter number of columns: '))

if rows < 3 and columns < 3:

    print('Invalid input')

else:

    for r in range(rows):

        for c in range(columns):

            print(int(c+r+1) % 2, end=' ')

        print()
```

Comment: What is `if rows and columns < 3 or rows and columns % 2:` supposed to do and where do you define `dimension`?

Comment: Is it intended to work with an even number of rows or columns?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is blatantly homework, and no decent attempt at solving the problem has been made.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> rows = columns = 5
>>> for r in range(rows):
...   for c in range(columns):
...     print("1" if r == rows//2 or c == columns//2 else "0", end=" ")
...   print()
... 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
```